# Switching iCloud account within an app

Tags: ios, icloud

Does anyone know, if the iCloud account can be also switched within the application (without changing the iCloud account under the Settings)?

So let's say I have one device (A), which may be shared among N users (the users will have to authenticate before they can access the applications features), I also want their data to be backed up so they could be synced to another device (B).

Can this be accomplished using Apples's iCloud services or is a 3rd party provider the only solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Apple gives you no control over logging in and out of iCloud. That is completely handled by the Settings app and Apple's own frameworks.